# Usage of DTOs to handle json data in JavaScript projects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects, dto

In almost every JavaScript project, using a framework or not, the data is gathered from an API and used raw on a JSON object, such as:

```
data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
```

This and its variants using Axios, Fetch API, etc, work fine. But why don't we use DTO classes for this data? We tend to use data from APIs, after fecthing it, in something like:

```
const Foo = (data) => {
    return( 
        <h1>data.someData</<h1>
    )
}
```

And for small data this works absolutely fine. But I wonder: JavaScript has the power of creating classes with attributes, constructors and methods. Why don't we use classes for these data? Surely it would be helpful when we deal with larger data, by creating data validation functions, etc. I searched for a while now, and found nothing on DTO objects and modern JavaScript programming.

Comment: Modern JS is converging to functional programming approach (see Redux, for example).
There's no reason to have a class with validation methods when you can write a function that takes in a raw data struct and returns validation result.

Comment: I think that's one of the reasons why TypeScript exists.

Comment: IMO, it is a waist of time to write classes that essentially convert object created by JSON parse into custom objects (instances of custom classes).
Especially with things TypeScript where JSON.parse is generic

Comment: I get your meaning, and I understand the migration to functional programming. However, model classes, only for the purposes of data validation and standartization, seems like a good idea. If we want to check something in a JSON data, somewhere we will have to build a function for that. So why not have DTOs?